# Cast constant generic with wildcard

Tags: java, generics, casting, unbounded-wildcard

I'm doing static util method which returns completed future with empty optional:

```
public class CompletableFutureUtils {

    private static final CompletableFuture<Optional<?>> EMPTY_FUT = completedFuture(Optional.empty());

    private static final Optional<?> EMPTY_OPT = Optional.empty();

    @Nonnull
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> CompletableFuture<Optional<T>> emptyOptionalCompletedFuture() {

        // COMPILE ERROR: incompatible types: CompletableFuture<Optional<?>> cannot be converted to CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>
        // return (CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>)EMPTY_FUT;

        return completedFuture((Optional<T>)EMPTY_OPT); // works, but creates new instance every time
    }
}
```

For the sake of efficiency i want to return the same constant instance of completed `CompletableFuture` - **EMPTY_FUT**, but can't cast it to `CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>` because of unbounded wildcard.

Of course i want to call this completed future method for any type, pretty much the same as [Optional.empty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#empty--) and [CompletableFuture.completedFuture(U)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completedFuture-U-)

How to cast generic with unbounded wildcard to specific type? Is it possible at all?

Comment: Due to type erasure `Optional<T>` and `Optional<?>` are the same at runtime, i.e. just `Optional`. Thus is you cast to the raw type the compiler would warn you but should do it without complaints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast away the type of the `CompleteableFuture` first, then cast again to the type you want, like this:

```
return (CompletableFuture<Optional<T>>) (CompletableFuture<?>) EMPTY_FUT;
```

Comment: awesome, thx. Didn't know about this "double casting with up casting"

Comment: ah, it could be even simplified upping bounds of EMPTY_FUT: `CompletableFuture EMPTY_FUT = completedFuture(Optional.empty());` Then `(CompletableFuture<?>) ` even not needed any more. Could you adjust/edit you answer with this approach? Thanks

Comment: You can, but just watch out, in case you accidentally reuse it as, say, a `CompleteableFuture<String>`. At least if you have it as a `CompleteableFuture<Optional<?>>`, you have to explicitly cast it away.

Comment: i see, just in this certain re-usage doesn't have any sense